# ListView OnItemClickListener not work

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview, listview-adapter

I sorted `listview` by category, by the following.

```
    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Reported Date"))
        {
            SortByRepDateAdapter sortAdapter= new SortByRepDateAdapter(getActivity(), defList);             
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Unit"))
        {
            sortByUnitAdapter sortByUnitAdapter= new sortByUnitAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortByUnitAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Block"))
        {
            SortByBlockAdapter sortByBlockAdapter= new SortByBlockAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortByBlockAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Last Followup Date"))
        {
            SortByLastFDateAdapter sortByLastFDateAdapter= new SortByLastFDateAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortByLastFDateAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Scope"))
        {
            SortByScopeAdapter sortByScopeAdapter= new SortByScopeAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortByScopeAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Subcontractor"))
        {
            SortBySubConAdapter sortBySubconAdapter= new SortBySubConAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortBySubconAdapter);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorted By "+
                  item.toString(),
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
    }
      });

          popupMenu.show();
      }
```

I sorted `listview` by calling different Adapters according to the category in menu.
The problem is after the `listview` is sorted, `listview.OnItemClickListener` not working.
I want to go new detail Activity when I click on each `listView` row. Please help me.

Here is my code.

```
public class RectificationAct extends Fragment implements OnDataRetrieveComplete, OnItemClickListener{
protected static final String TAG = RectificationAct.class.getSimpleName();
private View view;
private Button btnSort;
private ListView listDefect;

private ListViewAdapter adapter;
private WebHelper webHelper;
private String projId;
ArrayList<DefectRecord> defList= new ArrayList<DefectRecord>();
private ArrayList<ListItem_Defect> listItems=new ArrayList<ListItem_Defect>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    webHelper = new WebHelper(this);
    projId= FragHelper.getSF(StaticHelper.PROJID, getActivity());
    Log.i(TAG,"projID=>"+projId);
    webHelper.getDefectRecord(projId);
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_retification, container, false);
    listDefect=(ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_main);
    listDefect.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    btnSort=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btnSort);
    btnSort.setOnClickListener(onSortListener);
    return view;
}
final OnClickListener onSortListener= new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        showPopupMenu(v);
    }
};

private void showPopupMenu(View v){
       PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(getActivity(), v);
          popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_sort, popupMenu.getMenu());

          popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Reported Date"))
        {
            SortByRepDateAdapter sortAdapter= new SortByRepDateAdapter(getActivity(), defList);             
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Unit"))
        {
            sortByUnitAdapter sortByUnitAdapter= new sortByUnitAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortByUnitAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Block"))
        {
            SortByBlockAdapter sortByBlockAdapter= new SortByBlockAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortByBlockAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Last Followup Date"))
        {
            SortByLastFDateAdapter sortByLastFDateAdapter= new SortByLastFDateAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortByLastFDateAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Scope"))
        {
            SortByScopeAdapter sortByScopeAdapter= new SortByScopeAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortByScopeAdapter);
        }
        else if(item.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Subcontractor"))
        {
            SortBySubConAdapter sortBySubconAdapter= new SortBySubConAdapter(getActivity(), defList);
            listDefect.setAdapter(sortBySubconAdapter);
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sorted By "+
                  item.toString(),
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;
    }
      });

          popupMenu.show();
      }

@Override
public void onDataTaken(ArrayList<Block_Unit_Level>lvl_unt, ArrayList<DefectRecord> d_arr) {
    listItems.clear();
    defList=d_arr;
    /*for (Block_Unit_Level uLvl_Obj : lvl_unt) {
        listItems.add(new Block_Unit_Level(uLvl_Obj.get("block"), uLvl_Obj.get("level"), uLvl_Obj.get("unit")));*/

        for (DefectRecord defect : d_arr) 
        {

            /*if(uLvl_Obj.get("level").equalsIgnoreCase(defect.get("level")) && uLvl_Obj.get("unit").equalsIgnoreCase(defect.get("unit")))
            {*/

    //listItems.add(new Defect(defect.get("id"), defect.get("unit"), defect.get("level"), defect.get("scope_name"), defect.get("priority"), defect.get("description")));
                listItems.add(new DefectRecord(defect.get("unit"), defect.get("level"), defect.get("block"),
                        defect.get("created_date"), defect.get("sub_con"), defect.get("scope"), defect.get("followup"), 
                        defect.get("followup_date")));
            //}

        }
    //}
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), listItems);
    listDefect.setAdapter(adapter);

}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==StaticHelper.requestCode_Rect)
    {
        CommunicationHelper.update_in_photo_upload(getActivity());
        refreshView();
    }
}
public void refreshView()
{
    webHelper.getDefectRecord(projId);
}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Defect item = (Defect)listItems.get(position);
    String id=item.get("id");
    Intent intent = new Intent (getActivity(), Rectification_DetailAct.class);
    Bundle b=new Bundle();
    b.putString("defect_id", id);
    intent.putExtras(b);
    startActivityForResult(intent, StaticHelper.requestCode_Rect);
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **ListFrament** instead of **Fragment** hope it helps